# How to convert multiple string values per line from a txt file into csv using bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Supposed to be I have below contents of a txt file e.g.

input.txt

```
jane doe  
20  
USA  
john smith  
21  
USA
```

my desired output would be

output.csv

```
Name,Age,Country  
jane doe,20,USA  
john smith,21,USA
```

I have achieved this using powershell but I want to stick to the requirement which is using bash.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Are the spaces at the end of the lines intentional?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify how (item and record) separators should be escaped if occurring in the data (and there's no CSV standard), so simply disregarding it here.

If your input file `input.txt` encodes each item in a separate line, and you want to bundle every three lines into a single line, with items separated by commas, here are some examples:

- using `paste`:

```bash
echo "Name,Age,Country"; paste -sd,,'\n' input.txt
```

- using `xargs`:

```bash
echo "Name,Age,Country"; xargs -d'\n' -L3 printf '%s,%s,%s\n' < input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { OFS=","; print "Name", "Age", "Country" }
    { printf "%s%s", $0, (NR % 3 ? OFS : ORS) }
' input.txt
Name,Age,Country
jane doe,20,USA
john smith,21,USA
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using `awk` command such that it checks the remainder of the line number divided by 3(since we have `name`, `age` and `country`) to determine which field it should process. When it reaches the third field (country), it prints the three fields in the desired CSV format and appends the result to output.csv.
A sample would look like:

```bash
input="input.txt"
output="output.csv"

# Write the header separately to the output file
echo "Name,Age,Country" > $output

awk '{
    if (NR % 3 == 1) {
        name = $0
    } else if (NR % 3 == 2) {
        age = $0
    } else {
        country = $0
        print name "," age "," country
    }
}' $input >> $output
```

*[Demo here](https://replit.com/@msankrit/SkyblueImpartialRom-1)*

---

#### Alternative way:

Using a `while` loop:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

input="input.txt"
output="output.csv"

{
    # Write the header to the output file
    echo "Name,Age,Country"

    # Read the input file and process the data
    while IFS= read -r name
    do
        IFS= read -r age
        IFS= read -r country
        echo "$name,$age,$country"
    done < "$input"
} > "$output"
```

*[Demo here](https://replit.com/@msankrit/SkyblueImpartialRom#main.sh)*

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` and assuming well-formed input consisting of sets of three lines:

```
sed '
    1i\
Name,Age,Country
    N
    N
    s/"/""/g
    y/\n+/+\n/
    s/[^+",]*[",][^+]*/"&"/g
    y/+\n/,+/
' input.txt >output.csv
```

- first `s///` escapes (doubles) any double-quote characters, as is commonly done in CSV
- second `s///` wraps fields that contain double-quotes or commas
- `y///` is used to encode/recode newlines since some versions of sed don't interpret `[^\n]` to mean "not newline"

For example, this will convert:

```
jane doe
20
USA
john smith
21
USA
"freddie" lee kwan-ji
70
Korea, South
```

into:

```
Name,Age,Country
jane doe,20,USA
john smith,21,USA
"""freddie"" lee kwan-ji",70,"Korea, South"
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can just use paste:

```
echo 'Name,Age,Country'
paste -d, - - - <input.txt
```